# Connecting the closest points on circles with a line

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

Suppose I have the function `f[c_, z_] := z^2 + c` and the following collection of circles in the plane. This is a simple example with only three circles, disjoint and not nested, and lying on the real line. Take `comp[{x_, y_}] := x + y*I`.

```
Show[Table[Graphics[Line[ReIm[Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], i]]]], {i, 0, 2}]]
```

Given one circle, I would like to connect it to the closest circle (that isn't itself) by the shortest possible line. So in this example the lines would be the segments of the real line between the closest points of the circles. The following code does this manually.

```
Graphics[Line[
  ReIm[{Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, 
     Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], 0], 
    Map[comp, 
     Table[BezierFunction[{Map[ReIm, 
           Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, 
            Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], 0]][[750]], 
         Map[ReIm, 
           Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, 
            Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], 1]][[750]]}][
       s], {s, 0, 1, 0.001}]], 
    Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], 
     1], Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, 
     Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], 2], 
    Map[comp, 
     Table[BezierFunction[{Map[ReIm, 
           Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, 
            Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], 0]][[250]], 
         Map[ReIm, 
           Nest[f[-1.755, #] &, 
            Map[comp, CirclePoints[{0, 0}, 0.1, 1000]], 2]][[750]]}][
       s], {s, 0, 1, 0.001}]]}]]]
```

This is messy but it works. However for more circles this will become very tedious to implement. Is there a quicker way to do this? I would still like to get the points along the connecting lines for future calculations. Also, perhaps more difficult, what if the parameter `c` for `f[c,z]` is complex so the lines are no longer in a straight line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Building on @Cesareo's answer (especially his initial example configuration), but trying to take more advantage of built-in functionality...

```
(* generate initial example, like Cesareo's answer, but with explicit Circle data structure *)

SeedRandom[8]
circs = Circle @@@ Table[{RandomReal[{-20, 20}, 2], RandomReal[{1, 3}]}, 10];

(* define a center-to-center distance function *)
df[x_, y_] := EuclideanDistance[x[[1]], y[[1]]]

(*use it to determine neighbors*)
neighbors = NearestNeighborGraph[circs, DistanceFunction -> df,
   DirectedEdges -> False];

(*define a function to determine the minimal lines*)
minLine[edge_] := With[
  {p1 = RegionNearest[edge[[1]], edge[[2, 1]]],
   p2 = RegionNearest[edge[[2]], edge[[1, 1]]]},
  Line[{p1, p2}]]

(*generate a list of Lines, and then display the final result*)
lines = minLine /@ EdgeList[neighbors];
Graphics[{Red, lines, Black, circs}]
```

[image: display of final results. black circles with red lines]

Answer (score 10):

If I understood the question, the solution can be addressed as follows:

```
SeedRandom[8]
circs = Table[{RandomReal[{-20, 20}, 2], RandomReal[{1, 3}]}, 10];
nc = Length[circs];
grcircs = Table[Graphics[Circle[circs[[k, 1]], circs[[k, 2]]]], {k, 1, nc}];
dists = {};
For[i = 1, i <= nc, i++, {ci, ri} = circs[[i]];
 distmax = 1000;
 For[j = 1, j <= nc, j++,
  If[i != j,
   {cj, rj} = circs[[j]];
   d = Norm[ci - cj];
   dij = d - ri - rj;
   If[dij > 0, 
    If[dij < distmax,
     distmax = dij;
     d0 = d;
     ci0 = ci;
     cj0 = cj;
     ri0 = ri;
     rj0 = rj;
     j0 = j]
    ]
   ]
  ];
 AppendTo[dists, {distmax, d0, i, j0, ci0, cj0, ri0, rj0}]
 ]
grsegs = {};
For[i = 1, i <= nc, i++,
 {distmax, d, i0, j0, ci0, cj0, ri0, rj0} = dists[[i]];
 vij = (cj0 - ci0)/d;
 pi = ci0 + ri0 vij;
 pj = cj0 - rj0 vij;
 AppendTo[grsegs, ParametricPlot[mu pi + (1 - mu) pj, {mu, 0, 1}]]]
Show[grcircs, grsegs, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[distF]

distF[Circle[c1_, r1_], Circle[c2_, r2_]] := Norm[c1 - c2 - Normalize[c1-c2] (r1 + r2)]
```

We can use `distF` in two ways:

#### 1. `NearestNeighborGraph`

We get the desired picture using `NearestNeighborGraph` with the options `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` and `VertexShapeFunction -> (#2&)`:

```
ClearAll[nnG]
nnG = NearestNeighborGraph[#, DistanceFunction -> distF, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VertexShapeFunction -> (#2 &), 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Index", Center], DirectedEdges -> False, 
    VertexStyle -> Black, EdgeStyle -> Red] &;
```

***Examples:***

Using the list of circles `circs` from Cesareo's answer as an example input:

```
SeedRandom[8]
circs = Circle @@@ Table[{RandomReal[{-20, 20}, 2], RandomReal[{1, 3}]}, 10];

nnG @ circs
```

[image]

A simpler example:

```
SeedRandom[8]
circs2 = Circle @@@ Transpose[{3 CirclePoints[3], RandomReal[{.1, 1}, 3]}];

nnG @ circs2
```

[image]

#### 2. `Nearest`

We identify the nearest neighbor of each circle and construct a line between each circle and its nearest neighbor:

```
ClearAll[nF, shortestLine]

nF[cl : {__Circle}] := Last @ Nearest[cl, #, 2, DistanceFunction -> distF] &;

shortestLine[Circle[c1_, r1_], Circle[c2_, r2_]] := Module[{nrml = Normalize[c1 - c2]},
  Line[{c1 - r1 nrml, c2 + r2 nrml}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Graphics[{circs, Red, shortestLine @@@ Transpose[{circs, nF[circs] /@ circs}]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{circs2, Red, shortestLine @@@ Transpose[{circs2, nF[circs2] /@ circs2}]}]
```

[image]

***Note:*** The distance function `df` in accepted answer ignores the radii when identifying `neighbors`. Although it happens to give correct answer for input `circs`, for input `circs2` it gives

[image]